# VB.NET - Binding filtered accents

Tags: vb.net, filter, binding, diacritics

I have a DataGrid with BindingSource and I need filter without and with accents. 
BindingSource.Filter don't let it use "COLLATE" in the query. Therefore, I use patterns in the query but I get this error:

```
Error in the Like operator: The string pattern '% [E, È-Ë]%' is invalid.
```

And the query is:

```
WHERE Name LIKE '%[E,È-Ë]%'
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the [documentation for LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx), your pattern is indeed invalid. Hence the error message.

Comment: Hi @peterG. And how can I do it? 
Here it explains what can be done: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/gg251796.aspx

Comment: Hi the link you provided appears to be to the MS Office implementation, so is misleading. The link I provided is to the correct docs for vb, (although in English). However, there is an 'IN' available in the list of reserved words so I would give this a try. Unfortunately there appears to be no example of correct syntax though.